# Results depending if value found excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 columns with names list. All columns are from different excel files. I want the value from cells from column E to change in Y or N depending if the value from column D is found in other columns A,B,C:

```
-Y: (if D is found in A) 
-N: (if D is found in A and B) or (if D is found in C) or (if D is not found in A and B and C)
```

This is what i have until now :

```
Sub find_if_in_a_and_b()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Findcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
If Trim(Findcell) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
Sub find_if_in_a_and_b_and_c()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Findcell = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
If Trim(Findcell) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Any help is welcomed.Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to use VBA?  This looks like it would be a simple countif formula

Comment: I agree with @Phil. This can be done using formula. Not unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi, i have tried with count if, conditional format, 5 if's ... but it just doesn't work .

Comment: Do you want to test **D1** against **A1,B1,C1** or against all of columns **A,B,C** ??

Comment: Hi, case 1 : search D1 in range A:B and if not found search In range C:C . If dind't find E1 shows Y . case 2 : search D1 in range A:A - if found, E1 show N .

Comment: Your logic is unclear.  Can you provide a logic table?  Eg: found a=true,found b=false, found c=false e="Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mates said, you dont need VBA. Make 3 auxiliary columns with "Found in A" "Found in B" "Found in C" with this formula `COUNTIF(A:A;$D2)` and check for Y or N. Check this image[image]

Comment: Hi, i did just that, but... : column H should show me Y if he found D2 in :  A and B **or**  C  **or** not found in A and B and C . And it should show N if he found D2 only in A .

Comment: =IF(OR(AND(E2=1;F2=1;C2=0);AND(E2=0;F2=0;C2=0));"Y";"N")