# Search for a word in one Column

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I have two columns. Column "A" One having a list of 100 words and other column "B" having 20 words. I wish to make a third column "C" stating if the word from "B" exists in "A" or not. I want to know how this can be achieved using a formula in excel

Comment: Check [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Asked and answered extensively, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070404/results-depending-if-value-found-excel-vba/37071389#37071389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In C1 Cell**

=IF(B1="","",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1),"Yes","No"))

Drag the above formula down.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that was perfect! what i wanted!